# Implementing double tap in OpenFlow

Tags: objective-c, ipad

What's the best way to implement a double tap that will display a new view controller when using OpenFlow (https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow).

Tried amending `touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ViewDidLoad (same view that loads the OpenFlow)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:    (AFOpenFlowView *)self action:@selector(GetSeries)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```